# How to remove multiple outer braces in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

### I tried to iterate the following array, an array with multiple outer square brackets as in string but I couldn't manage to find a solution. Could someone know how to remove the first outer square bracket?

```
//Original array
           var multipleBraceArray = "[
          [
            [-74.026675, 40.683935],
            [-74.026675, 40.877483],
            [-73.910408, 40.877483],
            [-73.910408, 40.683935]
          ]
        ]";

        //This is the output I am looking for:
              var singleBraceArray = [
              [-74.026675, 40.683935],
              [-74.026675, 40.877483],
              [-73.910408, 40.877483],
              [-73.910408, 40.683935]
            ];
```

Comment: It's just array (of arrays :)) inside an array. `multipleBraceArray[0]`

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided the code you've written (that isn't working).

Answer (score 1):

You're just looking for the first element of your `multipleBraceArray`

```js
var multipleBraceArray = [[[-74.026675, 40.683935], [-74.026675, 40.877483], [-73.910408, 40.877483], [-73.910408, 40.683935]]];

var singleBraceArray = multipleBraceArray[0];

console.log(singleBraceArray);
```

Comment: I have tried it that way but it still giving me different result but on I tried it on the google console it works. Thank you for answering.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple errors:

1. Javascript doesn't let you do strings over multiple lines without using a template literal (backtick) or the `\` character to signal a line-end
2. You're starting with the input as an `Array` in a `String`, not an `Array`.

Try using this instead:

```
var arr =JSON.parse("[[[-74.026675, 40.683935],[-74.026675, 40.877483],[-73.910408, 40.877483],[-73.910408, 40.683935]]]");
```

Comment: Your answer is right, but javascript lets you write strings over multiple lines if you end your line with backslash "one line \ other line" or you don't even need backslash if you use template strings